# Postfix SASL error

Tags: linux, postfix, email, sasl, smtp-auth

I'm trying to configure my postfix server to accept connections from outside mail clients using SASL authentication with dovecot. It was previously setup with cyrus sasl.

However when I try to send mail from another server using Mozilla Thunderbird, I get lines like these in my maillog file:

```
warning: SASL authentication problem: unable to open Berkeley db /etc/sasldb2: No such file or directory
warning: SASL authentication failure: no secret in database
warning: SASL CRAM-MD5 authentication failed: authentication failure
```

These are lines in my main.cf config file:

```
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    reject_invalid_hostname
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain


smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_unauth_destination
    reject_non_fqdn_sender
    check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/pop-before-smtp,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rbl_client psbl.surriel.com

  smtpd_sasl_path = dovecot
  smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
  smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
  smtpd_sasl_security_options = noplaintext noanonymous
  broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
```

I've also checked the config files */usr/lib/sasl/smtpd.conf* and */etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf* and I have:

```
pwcheck_method:saslauthd
mech_list: plain login
```

I have no idea why postfix keeps giving me the sasldb2 and cram-md5 authentication error. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

saslauthd can handle only PLAIN and LOGIN authentication methods but you have disabled plaintext with smtpd_sasl_security_options. Also you have typo in your config - smtpd_sasl_path statement is duplicated, it seems first one should be typed as smtpd_sasl_type instead.

Check http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html for additional details.

Comment: Thanks. That solved it. I feel like an idiot for missing the typos. I would vote you up but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: You can accept his answer, even if you don't have enough rep to upvote it.